# rename a long list of randomly named folders (with the eventual aim of extracting a file from each one)

Tags: python, directory, rename

Using Python, I would like to rename a list of sub-folders (each sub-folder contains one pdf file).  I can't find code that will just extract the files without knowing the name of each sub-folder so I figured maybe I should start by at least naming each sub-folder sequentially so that I might find a way from there....

I have this code for renaming files which I've tried to adapt but I got an error.  I'm not a coder. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
def rename_folders(path, new_name):
    
    os.chdir(path)
    
    for (i, folderame) in enumerate(natsorted(os.listdir(path))):
        os.rename(src=foldername, dst ='{}{}{}'.format(new_name,i+1))
rename_folders('C:/Users/me/Dropbox/TASK/','file1')
```

The error I got:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 rename_folders('C:/Users/dwallace/Dropbox/HOLDING FILE/TASK/','file1')
>
> in rename_folders(path, new_name)
> 4
> 5     for (i, folderame) in enumerate(natsorted(os.listdir(path))):
> ----> 6         os.rename(src=foldername, dst ='{}{}{}'.format(new_name,i+1))
>
> NameError: name 'foldername' is not defined

Comment: An example of the folder names I currently have: 0004440548, 0027484684,0034990114 which is why I want to rename them to something generic e.g. f1, f2, f3

Comment: I've discovered there is a simple way to get the pdfs out using the search bar, but I would still like to know how to rename folders because it will help me in other situations. :-)

Comment: You have a typo in your code. You are iterating over `folderame` instead of `forldername`, this is where the NameError originates from.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
import os

def rename_folders(path, new_name):
    # get sub-directories of path
    sub_dirs = sorted(next(os.walk(path))[1])

    # loop throuhg sub-dirs to rename
    for (i, sub_dir) in enumerate(sub_dirs):
        # set names
        src_dir = os.path.join(path, sub_dir)
        dst_dir = os.path.join(path, '{}_{}'.format(new_name, i + 1))

        # do renaming
        os.rename(src=src_dir, dst=dst_dir)

rename_folders('C:/Users/me/Dropbox/TASK/', 'file')
```

Comment: I pasted the above script as is into Jupyter notebook which is what I'm using and it didn't do anything. Was I meant to define any of the things in the script?

Comment: Nothing happen because you did not execute the function. The code snippet just defines the renaming function. You need to add:

    rename_folders('C:/Users/me/Dropbox/TASK/', 'file')